# Failed to start service, error 2. TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle

i have start oracle services but its giving error:
windows could not start the 
OracleOraDb11g_home1ClrAgent Service on local computer.
Error2: the system cannot find the file specified.

Also there are multiple services OracleORaDbHome1 and OracleOraDbhome2.

Comment: What file isn't being found? Sounds like something may have been deleted or have the wrong access permissions set.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the tnsnames.ora file in below navigation directory:

Drive_Name:\OraHome_1\network\ADMIN

2. Check the file property with installed oracle service details

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10..)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = PLSExtProc)
    )
  )

3. Also check the tnslistener along with it's service.